# A single key for Input source switching on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: shortcut-keys

Is there any single key left that both Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and LibreOfice 7.3.2.2 do not use it as shortcut keys ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install GNOME shell extension and configure shortcuts as you wish.

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/6066/shortcuts-to-activate-input-methods/

Answer (score 0):

1. Install GNOME extension [Eval-GJS](https://github.com/ramottamado/eval-gjs) - This extension provides unrestricted Eval() dbus method for running arbitrary code in the compositor.

> ```
> https://github.com/ramottamado/eval-gjs.git
> cd eval-gjs
> make install
> ```

2. Install gnome-shell-extension-manager

> ```
> sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-manager
> ```

3. Logout and re-login
4. Launch gnome-shell-extension-manager and enable Eval-GJS
5. Go to Settings -> Keyboard -> Keyboard Shortcuts and add a custom shortcut with the following command:

> ```
> gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /dev/ramottamado/EvalGjs --method dev.ramottamado.EvalGjs.Eval "imports.ui.status.keyboard.getInputSourceManager().inputSources[0].activate()"
> ```

Replace the index in `inputSources[0]` with the actual index of the input method you wish to change to. First layout will be `inputSources[0]`, second layout will be `inputSources[1]` and so on.

Comment: I have 2 computers. The first one I had upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 to 21.10 and 22.04 respectively at the same time on the day that 22.04 was released, and this problem happened. On the other hand, for the second one, I had waited for a week until the Software Updater mentioned the upgrading from 20.04 to 22.04 directly. This problem did not happened on the second computer. So, I did the clean installation on the first computer. This problem did not happen.